# Eclipse can't find Java runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

My problem is that I am trying to download the Eclipse IDE but when I do, it says that I do not have the latest version of Java

It says I need Java version 8 (build version 1.8.0) and I also have Java 8 but it is written as build version 1.8.0_221_b11.

I do not know how to fix this. I have tried re-installing Java but that did not work.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: Add the `-vm` setting to your eclilse.ini and point it to a proper jdk

Comment: What platform are you on? Windows or linux? (Or something else?) What Eclipse version are you trying to install? Do you have only one Eclipse version installed? Do you have only one JDK installed?

Comment: Have you set the JAVA_HOME environment variable?

Comment: Also, who says that you do not have the latest Java version? Do you get the error during the installation of Eclipse IDE or when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the Eclipse installer rather than downloading a full package. Help for the installer is available at https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer

Reason for suggesting the installer: it has more smartness for detecting different Java installations on your system and picking one that is suitable for running Eclipse.

If this still doesn't solve your problem, you may use the menu (upper right) to switch to "Advanced Mode" where you can inspect the Java installations found by the installer, and select or add the desired version (close to the bottom, look for "Java 1.8+ VM:").